# Remote Desktop Woes Since changing to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I work from home and I remote into a desktop at my work.  For several years I have used a Windows 7 based PC at home and a Windows 10 PC at work.

When I remoted from my Windows 7 PC into my Windows 10 PC it all worked great.  Unfortunately, my Windows 7 PC was old enough that my company made me do a "Mandatory Upgrade", which means they took my PC and gave me a new one running Windows 10.  (So now both are running Windows 10.)

I am now having issues with my remote desktop freezing while working.  It seems to be the most likely to freeze during these actions:

- Moving a Window (Click and drag.  Using the windows key + Arrow is fine.)
- Scrolling in my Powershell window (with a lot of text in the buffer).
- Alt+Tab

It never seems to freeze during just normal typing.  In about 1 out of 20 times it will recover and I can keep working.  Most of the time I have to kill my Remote Desktop connection and re-connect. That only takes a few seconds, and when I am back in, it all works fine until the next time it freezes.

When I check the connection icon, it says that the quality of the signal strength is excellent and that it is using UDP.  It will say that even if it is frozen.

Is there anyway to debug this issue?  It seems to be happening more and more and it is starting to get frustrating!

Comment: It is not an endemic Windows 10 issue and I really think your company should take back the computer and make it work. They may not have set it up properly.. I have been using Windows 10 for remote business access for some years now.

Comment: It seems there is a known issue in Windows 10 version 1809 to 1903. The solution is to disable the UDP protocol from local group policy on the client. Computer Configuration > Administration Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Connection Client > Turn Off UDP On Client. You can have a try to see if it is also your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a known problem.  At any rate, I have had similar problems.  I have no simple solution to offer. Forgive me for stating the obvious, but switching to a home computer running Windows 10 might be the path of least resistance. As a different workaround, Teamviewer offers remote control functionality that does not depend on either the Windows version or Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Remote Desktop on Windows 10 for several years to:

Other Windows 10 machines.
Windows Servers.

No problems with RDP freezing over periods of hours of use.

You need to make sure:

1. Windows is right up to date.
2. All Drivers (including BIOS) are up to date.

And then make sure settings are correct. That is up to your company (ask them) as we cannot know what they are doing at their end. Make especially sure about SMBv1 as it is gone. Ask the company.

But do know, what you want works reliably for me and also for my colleagues and user colleagues doing the same thing. All done with Windows 10 as our businesses ditched Windows 7 just prior to the end of its support period.